# Getting "0" in simple mathematical function through window function

Tags: sql-server, mathematical-expressions

I need to find the percent the product was on shelf.

So I use this query:

```
select 
    *, 
    cast((t1.CountProd / t1.SumProd)*100 as dec(12,10)) as asasa
from 
   (select 
        *,
        count(Nalichie) over (partition by ProductID) as CountProd,
        count(Nalichie) over() as SumProd
    from 
        [saleit_db_Danone].[OSA].[tbl_FullFCompetitive]) as t1
```

Why do I get `0` in the last column?

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: Cast the columns `t1.CountProd` and `t1.SumProd` explicitly. At the moment you are doing an integer division `1936 / 202223 = 0`.

Comment: I know that.
But how to get a correct answer?

Comment: Make them *not* integers.  Cast both columns separately before doing the division, not after.

Answer (score 3):

As per comment, you are doing an integer division then casting to a decimal afterwards. Try this:

```
select
    *,
    (CAST(CountProd AS DEC(16, 10)) / SumProd) * 100 AS asasa
from (
    select
        *,
        count(Nalichie) over (partition by ProductID) as CountProd,
        count(Nalichie) over() as SumProd
    FROM [saleit_db_Danone].[OSA].[tbl_FullFCompetitive]
) as t1
```

Comment: Up vote, but I have an additional note.  Based on the numbers in the screenshot this leads to an Arithmetic overflow error (when I ran it anyway), so I think @Andrey will need to increase the size of the datatype.  I went up to DEC(16,10) and it worked with the example data.

Comment: thats won't working. Becose first sql find count ant it is alredy int and then you try to convert into decimal.Ypu will receive an converting error.
Solve this trick by adding an `t1.CountProd + 0.0` without converting

Comment: If `CountProd ` and `SumProd ` are integer - that will cause arithmetic overflow error on converting

Comment: Updated to `DEC(16,10)`. Tested and working. See [working example](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/905343507347cfa309a7fd708c722837).

Answer (score 0):

Also if you convert into numeric instead decimal  you will get a correct answer.